Is unwrapped connection returned to Hikari connection pool in springboot (spring-data-jpa)
I have a spring-boot REST API which calls Stored Procedure from Oracle database. I have implemented Hikari connection pooling and specified JDBC connection credentials in application.properties.
The class which makes connection to database and stored procedure is:

@Component
public class StoredProcedureConnector {

    @PeristenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;
    
    public void executeStoredProcedure() {
        OracleConnection oracleConnection = entityManager.unwrap(OracleConnection.class);
        try(OracleCallableStatement statement = 
                (OracleCallableStatement) oracleConnection .prepareCall("{call MY_PROCEDURE(?,?)}")){
            //set values in statement
            statement.execute();
        }
    }
}


I need to unwrap database connection because my code depends on OracleConnection class.
I used OracleCallableStatement inside try-with-resources to make sure statements closes after the execution.
My question is - Is my 'oracleConnection' connection returned back to the Hikari connection pool automatically? Please advise on this, I need to avoid any database leaks afterwards.
I know what normal direct connection returns to pool after its usage in springboot. But, in this scenarios I am unwrapping database connection to use OracleConnection class.
